# What data/functionality would you want to have available through a web API that isn't available today?

Tags: web-services, rest, screen-scraping

Have you ever looked for a web API for certain data or functionality, only to find that there isn't an API available to meet your needs, or that the APIs that are available are inadequate for some reason? I am really interested in collecting such experiences.

Please note that I am **not** asking about specific sites / web apps (so, for example, "*I wish there was an API for CraigsList*" or "*I wish there was an API for Orbitz*" are not appropriate answers). But what I **am** asking about is specific data/functionality (for example, "*I wish there was an API to retrieve historical stock quotes for Asian markets*" or "*I wish there were better APIs that allow me to send a fax to a physical fax machine*" would be good answers).

Bonus points if you provide some detail on how you would use the data/functionality that you're looking for, and if you can say whether you would pay for access to such an API or not. Thanks!

Comment: sounds like business plan research more than a concrete question about webservices

Comment: Perhaps this would belong in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?  The answer to this question couldn't possibly involve any code.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the distinction.  A web API doesn't make much sense without a specific service behind it.  "I wish there was an API for airline flights" only makes sense if you have something like Orbitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More (easier?) accessibility to consume government accounting and spending.  [People have compiled lists](http://www.programmableweb.com/featured/government-mashups-and-apis) of the available APIs but things are still all over the place.  [This poster](http://www.wallstats.com/deathandtaxes/) is and awesome start.  The nerds of the world could really have a field day with data sets that large.